# How to handle email verification if trying to return to mobile app after pressing link?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

**Behavior Wanted**: When I press the Sign Up button in my app, it sends a verification link to the specified email and navigates to a verification page within the mobile app that alerts the user that a verification email was sent. Then user can go to own email and click on the link that will verify the user and then direct them back to the verification page where it will reload the user and send them to the home page.

**Question**: What do I need to do in order to handle this?

**Things I have done**:

1. I have a custom domain, let's call it `customdomain.com`. I have set this up with firebase hosting.
2. I have created a dynamic link in the firebase console called `customdomain.com/verify`
3. I have created ActionCodeSettings to pass to the sendEmailVerification() function:

   ```
   String url = 'https://customdomain.com/verify/';
   String androidPackage = 'com.example.customdomain';
   String iosPackage = 'com.example.customdomain';
   ActionCodeSettings actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings(url: url, handleCodeInApp: true, android: {"packageName": androidPackage, "installApp": true, "minimumVersion": 21}, iOS: {"bundleId": iosPackage}, dynamicLinkDomain: 'https://customdomain.com/verify');
   Future<void> verifyEmail(ActionCodeSettings actionCodeSettings) async {
       User userRegister = _auth.currentUser;
       if (!userRegister.emailVerified) {
           await userRegister.sendEmailVerification(actionCodeSettings);
       }
    }
   ```
4. I have set my androidManifest.xml and build.gradle to handle dynamic links.

**Assumptions Made**:

1. I can use ValueNotifier on my verification page to listen to changes in isEmailVerified.
2. I need to change my email template to create custom email action handler?(https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler ?)
3. I don't need to create a web page on my customdomain.com to handle email verification.
4. I will be able to parse the actionCode from the url that was sent to the email for verification.

So just a couple of questions around this. Do I need to have my own custom server in order to handle email verification like this? Can this all be done through the firebase console? When I'm sending the email, am I sending a dynamic link or is the email template sending what is in the console?

I can't find any example of someone implementing this in flutter, so if anyone can point my in the right direction. I've been struggling with thinking about what is it all that I need in order to get this done. If you need more information for clarification, please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to have my own custom server in order to handle email
> verification like this? Can this all be done through the firebase
> console?

Firebase can handle all the process for email verification in Firebase Auth.

> When I'm sending the email, am I sending a dynamic link or is the
> email template sending what is in the console?

The email verification sent from Firebase Auth uses the [template](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/emails) from the Firebase console.

The Flutter code for sending email verification and verifying the link in the app is similar to what's in the docs for Android.

[Sending email link auth/verification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth#send_an_authentication_link_to_the_users_email_address)

```dart
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
var emailAuth = "someemail@domain.com";
void sendEmailVerification() {
  var acs = ActionCodeSettings(
      // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
      // URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
      url: "https://www.example.com/finishSignUp?cartId=1234",
      handleCodeInApp: true,
      iOSBundleId: "com.example.ios",
      androidPackageName: "com.example.android",
      androidInstallApp: true,
      androidMinimumVersion: "12");
  _auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail(
          email: emailAuth, actionCodeSettings: acs)
      .catchError(
          (onError) => print('Error sending email verification $onError'))
      .then((value) {
    print('Successfully sent email verification');
  });
}
```

[Verifying link and sign in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth#verify_link_and_sign_in)

```dart
void checkEmailLinkAuth(String emailLink) async {
  if (_auth.isSignInWithEmailLink(emailLink)) {
    await _auth
        .signInWithEmailLink(email: emailAuth, emailLink: emailLink)
        .catchError(
            (onError) => print('Error signing in with email link $onError'))
        .then((value) {
      // You can access the new user via value.user
      // Additional user info profile *not* available via:
      // value.additionalUserInfo.profile == null
      // You can check if the user is new or existing:
      // value.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser;
      var userEmail = value.user;
      print('Successfully signed in with email link!');
    });
  }
}
```